# Tracking device location in Mapbox in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mapbox

I have built a map by Mapbox library writen by Naxam.I have loaded map into my program and now i want to recycle this code from java into xamarin
But it seem to be error at this code

```
 private static class MainActivityLocationCallback  implements LocationEngineCallback {

    private final WeakReference activityWeakReference;

    MainActivityLocationCallback(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
    }

    /**

    The LocationEngineCallback interface's method which fires when the device's location has changed.
    @param result the LocationEngineResult object which has the last known location within it.
    */
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
    MainActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
    if (activity != null) {
    Location location = result.getLastLocation();

    if (location == null) {
    return;
    }

    // Create a Toast which displays the new location's coordinates
    Toast.makeText(activity, String.format(activity.getString(R.string.new_location),
    String.valueOf(result.getLastLocation().getLatitude()), String.valueOf(result.getLastLocation().getLongitude())),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // Pass the new location to the Maps SDK's LocationComponent
    if (activity.mapboxMap != null && result.getLastLocation() != null) {
    activity.mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().forceLocationUpdate(result.getLastLocation());
    }}}
```

:< Any one can help me

Comment: You posted Java code, do you have the C# code that is causing you error (and what is the error)

Comment: That is my code what i want to recycle.I have just write this:public class MainActivityLocationCallback : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationEngineCallback
{
    
    public new void Dispose()
    {
      
    }

    public void OnFailure(Java.Lang.Exception p0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b");
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object p0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
    }
}but it don't run